# how to connect to sybase and execute sql file using cmd

Tags: sql, cmd, sybase, sap-ase

I want to connect to sybase than execute a file.sql
I tapped this command:

```
sql -U Login -P MotDePasse -S ServeurASE -d NomDeLaBase -i Script.sql -o JournalDErreur.log
```

I also tried

```
isql -U Login -P MotDePasse -S @IPserveur:Port -d NomDeLaBase -i Script.sql -o JournalDErreur.log
```

and I have the error :

```
"La commande sql n'est pas reconnue'
```

Can u help please?

I have installed JTDS and sql (pip install) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to connect to a Sybase ASE database, and you're using the `isql` command line utility that comes with ASE (or the Sybase SDK), the correct `isql` format is:

```
isql -U <login> -P <password> -S <host_or_ipaddr>:<port> -D <dbname> -i <input_script> -o <output_file>
```

So updating your example we get:

```
isql -U Login -P MotDePasse -S IPserveur:Port -D NomDeLaBase -i Script.sql -o JournalDErreur.log
```

I can't speak for your `sql` example as I'm not familiar with that tool let alone its input parameters.

Comment: Even using this command I have the error '"La commande isql n'est pas reconnue' I think I must install another thing or define environnement variable

Comment: Assuming you're using `isql` from a ASE or SDK installation, there should be some resource files under the $SYBASE directory, eg, for a linux/UNIX environment you would source the $SYBASE/SYBASE.sh script (*.csh if using csh); these resource files should have all the env variables you'll need to get `isql` working

Comment: I think the problem is how to configure JTDS in my PC. Can u help me to resolve this problem please!

Comment: can you help please ?